# Quick one ,what is the appropriate regex to match any number greater than 750 ? in the below test content?

Tags: regex, pcre

what is the appropriate regex to match any number greater than "750 active" in the below text at the last line ?

```
=============================================================================
c0000000a7470b30 Y--P--- 4207362  weblogic -        c000000098078f98 0    1     1832876  0
c0000000a74853f0 Y--P--- 4376431  krizzsa  LL2CE414 c0000000a19479b8 0    8     70173    170
c0000000b3a1f2c8 Y--P--- 3996541  weblogic -        c0000000acd54f90 0    1     64112    0
c0000000b3a22418 Y--P--- 4371951  tinpatel tK       c000000098385b70 0    1     62       0
c0000000b3a286b8 B--PR-- 4385816  ayaw     SL5CG752 c00000001b0bdde0 0    5     14452    701
c0000000b3a2afd0 Y--P--- 4383560  sognenov t3       c000000099afe900 0    1     100      0
c0000000b3a2b808 Y--P--- 4368082  wenpli   66       c00000009e6f8260 0    1     461      0
c0000000b3a2c878 Y--P--- 4228342  sarbrar  tc       c0000000a62da668 0    1     0        0
c0000000b3a2f9c8 Y--P--- 4384060  weblogic -        c0000000a2deb910 0    1     0        0
c0000000b3a35430 Y--P--- 4383243  nakahmed t1       c00000009e0b9ce8 0    1     17       0
c0000000b3a38580 Y--P--- 3937012  mvvinay  76       c0000000a162a888 0    1     0        0
c0000000b3a3d7b0 Y--P--- 616042   neminhas LD2UA442 c0000000aea25ca8 0    2     0        0
c0000000b3a43218 Y--P--- 4383236  nakahmed t1       c0000000981b4570 0    1     37       22
c0000000b3a473d8 Y--P--- 4382647  viwang   2UA40922 c0000000a268a2d0 0    7     75275    4856
 412 active, 2176 total, 441 maximum concurrent
================================================================
```

in the last line if the active connections to a DB goes more than 750 we need to match it and do further processing.So can someone please help with regex ?
Please note that there is a space in the beginning of the last line.

Answer (score 2):

If it's Perl, there's no need to use matching for everything.

```
if (/ ([0-9]+) active/ && $1 > 750) {
    print "Matching!\n";
```

If you need a single regex, it's

```
 /^\ (?:  7 (?:   5 [1-9]
             | [6-9][0-9])
       | [89]  [0-9]{2}
       | [1-9][0-9]{3,})\ active/x
```

or shortly

```
/^ (?:7(?:5[1-9]|[6-9][0-9])|[89][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3,}) active/
```

Comment: we cannot use this.. need to one liner to match 
" <number greater than 750> active," -- please look at the last line. 
there is a space in the beginning. 
the number before the word "active" is variable.

Comment: Why can't you use it?

Comment: Thanks for the help but cannot use it as i am not using the complete perl code to parse the text file. i need to apply the regex in a ready made tool. which supports limited perl compatible regex.

Comment: Updated. Let's hope the tool supports all the constructs you need.

Comment: Perl compatible regex is not Perl regex unless the tool is actually running Perl. Despite the name. Please use the pcre tag in the future for this.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best idea, yet if we might have to, probably our expression would be:

```
^\h*(7[5-9]\d|[89]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})\h+active\b
((7[5-9]\d|[89]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})\sactive)
((7[5-9]\d|[89]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})\s+active)
((7[5-9]\d|[89]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,}) active)
```

based on [bobble-bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)'s advice,

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IqMayd/1)

or something similar to:

```
([7][5-9][0-9]|[8-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,}) active
(([7][5-9][0-9]|[8-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,}) active)
```

if we might want to capture things, separately.

Comment: tried this expression like below :
( [7][5-9][0-9]|[8-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,} active,)
but its not working..

Comment: @kaushikkm Just was trying something similar like Emmas answer. [Test here](https://regex101.com/r/IqMayd/1).

Comment: okeyy its working!! but the problem here is, i need this regex to apply in a tool which supports limited perl compatible regex. 
also wanted to know if we can have the complete regex inside parenthesis ? and not use \h and \b ?